# Pointer to array not working in function

Tags: c

so i have txt file that has 96k words, all arranged by order. I want to build a function that builds an array with the first an last index of a letter. For example if "a" goes from index 0 to index 100 and "b" from 101 to 150 on the txt file, the array stores {0,100,101,150,...}

Problem i have it's nothing comes from the output, and i think my code is right.

Can you detect what's the problem with it?

This is what i have:

```
#define PALAVRAS 96067
#define TAMANHO 25

typedef struct dicionario{
  char matrix[PALAVRAS][TAMANHO];
}*DICIONARIO;

void index_dic(DICIONARIO dic,int *lista){    
  int i=0,j;
  char c='a';
  lista[i]=0;

  for (j=0; j<PALAVRAS;j++)    //PALAVRAS is the number of words the txt has
    if (dic->matrix[j][0]!=c){ //if new letter is detected
      i++;                     //increments to next position in array
      lista [i]=j-1;           //stores last position of the last letter
      i++;                     //increments array again
      lista[i]=j;              //stores first position of the new letter
      c++;                     //increments to next letter
    }
}

int main(){
  int i,lista[35], *ponta=lista;
  struct dicionario dic;
  DICIONARIO x = &dic;
  FILE *fp;

  fp=fopen("dicio.txt", "r");
  for (i=0;i<PALAVRAS;i++)
    fgets (dic.matrix[i], TAMANHO,fp); //reads txt to matrix
  index_dic(x,ponta); //runs function with pointers as parameters
  for (i=0;lista[i]!='\0';i++)
    printf ("%d\n", lista[i]); //to print all the elements of the array
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Does it show any errors, or does it compile fine, just shows nothing?

Comment: hi @OnlineCop, it compiles just fine. Problem is that it doesn't show nothing.

The only thing missing on the code above is the define of variables PALAVRAS and TAMANHO

Comment: I don't see this `TAMANHO` defined in main or as global variable? But you are using it in `main()`. How?

Comment: hi @rsz yeah you are right, the only thing missing are the define of those variables. Let me edit the code. two seconds.

Comment: Same with PALAVARAS. You should try debugging on your own a bit TBH.

Comment: While you're at it, I assume you meant to call `index_dic`, not `ind_dic` at the end?

Comment: and are you sure that there is a file called `"dicio.txt"`? You should probably add some code to check that the `fp` was initialized properly: `if (!fp) { perror("Unable to open file"); return 1; }`

Comment: You have very bad programming habits. What if the file has one line less or more? Everything will break. Are you absolutely sure you read all the lines, and there is precisely as many as you say. Does your program end, does it fail? Its quite unlikely to finish with no output, unless the `lista` is empty. Have you debugged its filling?

Comment: The file is ok, i have tested other functions with it and it doesn't break. I only need to work with this file, "dicio.txt". That's not the problem. I could send you a link to the txt if you want.

Comment: You must make sure that `i` is less than `35` in `index_dic`. It's possible you are writing beyond the bounds of `lista`.

Comment: @RSahu hi there, but shouln't it be printing something? Even garbage. It doesn't print anything at all

Comment: You have a condition in there, don't you? If the program finishes with `0`. It means it didn't run the loop, and there is only one way for that to happen, the condition was false before the 1st iteration. Also this will probably will never-ever be useful to anyone else...

Comment: If you write a lot of code before you test any of it, you will fail. Start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and *never add to code that doesn't work*. If you had done this, you would have known that the problem wasn't in the function.

Comment: @luk32 what do you mean with finishes with 0? my condition is '\0' that's different from '0' right? I don't know if will be useful, i want to do this to optimize my search :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for loop won't print anything.

```
for (i=0;lista[i]!='\0';i++)
  printf ("%d\n", lista[i]);
```

Since you are setting `list[0]` to `0` in the following line in `index_dic`.

```
lista[i]=0;
```

**Update**

`list[i] != '\0'` is the same as `list[i] != 0`.

You use the form `list[i] != '\0'` to check when a null terminated C string ends. `list` is not that. It is a an array of integers. You have to find a different mechanism to check when the list of integers ends.

Comment: i see what you mean, but the condition "\0" is the end of the array right? lista[i]=0 is diferent from lista[i]='\0' Or am i missing something. I made it work if i put i<35 there...

Comment: No it's not. It's different from '0'.

Comment: Oh i see... I didn't know that. I allways thought that \0 mean the same as end of file.

Comment: `'\0'` is just an obfuscated way of writing `0`.